# Cheap way to remove scratches made on tinted window inside of car?

Tags: window, ice, scratch

What is the most cost efficient way (if any) to visually remove, or reduce as much as possible, scratches made on a tinted window inside of a car? The car is old, it does not matter if it's not perfect nor a permanent solution.

This was accidentally done with an ice scraper.  [This post](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/39625/how-to-best-deal-with-ice-buildup-on-inside-front-window-of-car) seems to say that it's safe to do that, but it's really not! I'm not attempting this with an ice scraper ever again.

[image]

Comment: I think your only option at this point is new tint.

Comment: Is only the tint damaged?

Comment: Yes, only the interior.  It was scratched with an ice scraper inside of the car, not outside.  Hope it answers your question, tough I would understand if not.  I cannot tell if the only thing that's scratched is the tint, but I would very much believe so, since I've never scratched glass with an ice scraper my entire life.

Comment: With a normal ice scraper, you'll never scratch glass ... they are only hard plastic and glass is ~6.5 on the Mohs hardness scale. Diamond is 10. Hardened steel is at 7 to 8. Iron is 4-5. Plastic? [It doesn't say](http://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Mohs_scale_of_mineral_hardness), but I'd put it somewhere between 2-2.5 (at a guess).

Comment: Crossing my fingers an user on here knows some compound/wax or something that I could polish with to reduce the visibility of those :-/

Comment: Seriously, the cheapest way to fix this is to do it yourself. Strip the old tint off, buy a new sheet, self install. This is left as a comment because *I don't know for **absolute** sure*, but honestly, I believe this is about your cheapest recourse.

Comment: Looks to be firmly in "replace tint" territory to me I'm afraid :(

Comment: Take the tint off and leave it off @that-ben, tinting your front windows reduces visibility and is a safety issue.

Comment: @GdD It's 100% OEM! Been driving this car daily for over 7 years and never had any accident.

Answer (score 1):

Try plastic wax sold at Wal-Mart for headlights it will smooth out light scratches made in tint which is a film but will not help where it is actually ripped torn or missing. Best bet is to re tint or diy with tint film you'll need a razor blade to trim edges some adhesive for tint and a card or plastic putty knife to smooth out ripples

Comment: It's not torn/ripped therefore I'll take a chance and try the plastic wax later today.  I'll keep you posted.  Thanks.

Comment: Haven't purchased the wax yet, been extremely busy, will come back here and report as soon as I try it :)